# PHP DOM: Get NodeValue excluding the child nodes

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have a variable`$content`containing a piece of HTML code :

```html
<b>AMZN 466.00 ( 15743 ) ( <span class='red'> -1 </span>) 
MSFT 290.00 ( 37296 ) ( <span class='red'> -2 </span>)
TWTR 4,000.00 ( 20 ) ( <span class=''> 0 </span>)</b>
```

Now, I want the values of `<b>`excluding the values of `<span>` using PHP DOM. How can this be done? A code snippet would be helpful.

So far, I've tried this:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$contents_i_want = $dom->getElementsByTagName('b');
foreach($contents_i_want as $content_i_want){ 
   $filtered_content = $content_i_want->nodeValue;
   echo $filtered_content;
}
```

Comment: can you share your expected output?

Comment: So, you have to find child nodes and remove'em

Comment: @SahilGulati I want the contents within the <b> tags excluding the contents within <span>. So, I expect my output to be something like this: AMZN 466.00 ( 15743 ) ( ) 
MSFT 290.00 ( 37296 ) ( )
TWTR 4,000.00 ( 20 ) ( )

Comment: @AparAdhikari Check my post hope that will help you out..

Comment: @u_mulder I just want the node values WITHOUT the child node values. If they can be removed, that would work for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you out..

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784456)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='<html><body><b>AMZN 466.00 ( 15743 ) ( <span class=\'red\'> -1 </span>) 
MSFT 290.00 ( 37296 ) ( <span class=\'red\'> -2 </span>)
TWTR 4,000.00 ( 20 ) ( <span class=\'\'> 0 </span>)</b></body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$dom->getElementsByTagName("b");

$xpath= new DOMXPath($dom);
$result=$xpath->query("//b/span");//here we are querying domdocument to find span which is inside b.

$nodesToRemove=array();//here we are maintaining an array of nodes which we want to remove
foreach($result as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);//removing nodes from its parent
}
 echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("b")->item(0)->textContent;//displaying content after removing nodes.
```

**Output:**

```
AMZN 466.00 ( 15743 ) ( ) 
MSFT 290.00 ( 37296 ) ( )
TWTR 4,000.00 ( 20 ) ( )
```

Comment: It worked. But could you please elaborate the line $result=$xpath->query("//b/span"); I am not that familiar to XPath. Thank You

Comment: @AparAdhikari I have explained the above post with comments, hope it will be more clear now. welcome.... :)