# How can I exclude the specific html block within body tag by using DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm using `DOMDocument` to get the HTML from a website. I want to get html within the `<body></body>` and I got it. But inside `body` here is a `<nav>...</nav>` block. How can I exclude `<nav></nav>` block only by using DOMDocument.

Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Title Here</title>
<head>
<?php
  $d = new DOMDocument;
  $mock = new DOMDocument;
  $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $d->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com'));
  $body = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
  foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
      $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
  }
  libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
  echo $mock->saveHTML(); //<body>.....</body>
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the accepted answer on this one,
[PHP DOM: Get NodeValue excluding the child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684272/php-dom-get-nodevalue-excluding-the-child-nodes)

You can remove 'nav' node just after gathering all child nodes of the body.